# Which generic collection to use?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics, collections

I have 2 separate classes:

- AreaProperties
- FieldProperties

1 AreaProperties can map to 1 FieldProperties. Without changing the design, I want a method to return a `List<>` of these objects

What generic collection in C# would be suitable?

I understand I can send 2 Lists and the function would look like:

```
public List<AreaProperties> Save(ref List<FieldProperties>)
{
    ..code
}
```

**EDIT:
Dror Helper's solution sounds good. However, I recently found out that there is no 1:1 between FieldProperties and AreaProperties.
How would I now handle this. I still want to go with a custom class that has an object of FieldProperties and AreaProperties but how would I handle the 1 to many scenario?**

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.  Can you clarify the question some?

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you're asking, but you almost certainly don't really want to pass your list by reference. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Please explain question with Code outline/ class struicture that would help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a class/struct that has two members - AreaProperties & FieldProperties and return a list of that class

```
class Pair<T1, T2>
{
     T1 t1;
     T2 t2;
}

List<Pair<AreaProperties, FieldProperties>> Save(){ ...}
```

Or use System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair instead (per Patrick suggestion below)

```
List<KeyValuePair<AreaProperties, FieldProperties>> Save(){ ... }
```

This way you keep the 1..1 relation as well.

**Edit:**
In case you need 1..n relation I think you want to return 
List>> instead this way you have a list of Field Properties for each AreaProperties you get back and you still keep the relation between them.

Comment: Shouldn't it be List<Pair> Save()?

Comment: There's already a Generic struct in .NET, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)

Comment: @Thomas Eyde It should be Pair<...> - thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Patrick McDonald you're right, you could us KeyValuePair<T1, T2> instead

Answer (score 3):

You could return a `List<KeyValuePair<AreaProperties, FieldProperties>>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic [`Dictionary<FieldProperties, AreaPropeties>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)? You will have to write your own [`Comparer<FieldPropeties>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) and [`KeyValuePair<FieldProperties, AreaProperties>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx).

Comment: Umh, why? He wants to map AreaProperties based on FieldProperties. seems to me FieldProperties should be the key, no?

Answer (score 0):

If the 1:1 relations needs to be enforced I recommend the struct method [Dror mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611930/which-generic-collection-to-use/611970#611970). If the 1:1 relation is not enforced I'd consider using the out parameter modifier.

```
void foo()
{
  List<AreaProperties> listArea;
  List<FieldProperties> listField;
}

void Bar(out List<AreaProperties> listArea, out List<FieldProperties> listField)
{
  listArea = new List<AreaProperties>();
  listField = new List<FieldProperties>();

}
```